# bridge traffic limiting via tc

Tags: linux, bandwidth, traffic-shaping, linux-networking, bandwidth-control

I have a Linux machine running as a bridge simulating various network conditions. I use `tc` for this. Introducing delays or packet loss is quite simple but I got into trouble trying to configure bandwidth limiting.
Can you, please, show me how to limit *all* the traffic going through my bridge *without any special rules and condition*, simply limit it to 1Mb/s?

Thanks.

PS Your favorite link to tc tutorial will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like (not tested)

```
tc qdisc add dev br0 root tbf rate 1mbit
```

Sorry but I do not now of any good tutorial, although I have not looked recently.

A very good manual (you might call it a tutorial) for not just "tc" can be found here:
http://www.lartc.org/howto/